# JavaScript -- Unable to understand Array.Map & Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have been working on a problem on FCC (Free code camp) which requires to scan a 2D array and find largest element from each 1D array and put the result into a 1D array. I came across this solution on GitHub was unable to understand it.

```
    function largestOfFour(arr) {
      return arr.map(function(group){
        return group.reduce(function(prev, current) {
          return (current > prev) ? current : prev;
        }, 0);
      });
    }
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

### OUTPUT IS [5, 27, 39, 1001]

My console.log(arr) gave me: 4,5,1,3,13,27,18,26,32,35,37,39,1000,1001,857,1

1. How did that 2D array get converted to 1D array when passed as a function parameter?

My console.log(group) gave me: 4,5,1,3 (first time), 13,27,18,26 (second time), 32, 35, 37, 39 (third time) and 1000, 1001, 857, 1 (fourth time).

2. How was the anonymous function able to take the parameter group as the individual 1D arrays inside the 2D.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you not understand map and reduce at all, or just how they're being used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the array.map() returns a new array by changing the values of the array you pass to it, in this case we're returning a function itself (array.reduce).

```
    arr.map(function(group))
```

arr.map takes in a 2D array called 'group' and reads each value inside it, in this case another array. So on the first run of 'map' the first array is [4, 5, 1, 3], we call reduce on it.

```
    group.reduce(function(prev, current)
```

On the first run of 'reduce' we have prev = 4 and current = 5 ("it starts on second value"), then in:

```
    return (current > prev) ? current : prev;
```

it asks is 5 bigger than 4?, if so return 5 else return 4. So it returns 5. 5 then is passed into 'prev' for the next run of 'reduce' we have prev = 5 (from last run) and current = 1.

```
    return (1 > 5) ? 1 : 5;
```

It returns 5 since it's bigger than 1.

```
    return (3 > 5) ? 3 : 5;
```

It returns 5 since it's bigger than 3. end of group.reduce(), the final returned value '5' is returned to arr.map(), the entire first array [4, 5, 1, 3] is replaced by a single value '5'. next run of arr.map() starts with the second array [13, 27, 18, 26].

I actually did that question on freecodecamp, and I didn't have to use map or reduce. I just read through using "double for loop / array.push / returning the array", although "map / reduce" is a lot cleaner and probably a better way of doing it. Hope that explains it

Answer (score 1):

When you use Array.map it will process each element within the array for example.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (item) { return item; } );
```

Will just return a **new** array with [1, 2, 3, 4], but say we double each value we could do it like this.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (item) { return 2 * item; });
```

Which returns [2, 4, 6, 8] back.

So in your example you have a 2 dimensional array. The Array.map works on the first level. So in each iteration the group is

- 1st -> [4, 5, 1, 3]
- 2nd -> [13, 27, 18, 26]
- 3rd -> [32, 35, 37, 39]
- 4th -> [1000, 1001, 857, 1]

So the 1st to 4th will then be passed into the Array.reduce function. Reduce just returns a single value based on the array passed in, or better put

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

What is happening in the reduce here is storing the maximum value, it begins with 0, and on the first iteration compares with the value 4. As 4 is larger than 0 it is stored and becomes our new max. It then tests against 5 and as 5 is bigger than 4 it stores that as the new max, and so on.

Once it finishes going through it produces a maximum for that array and gives a Number as the result. So now the first iteration of the map which contained an array is changed to a Number, in this case the first item of the Array produced by Array.map should be 5.

The final output I suspect would be

```
[5, 27, 39, 1001]
```